# Rails set session hash value from link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I need to set a flag in the session hash when a link is clicked (to toggle between basic/advanced views of a page). Is there a way to do this?

I'm thinking I can do it if I add a route for something like "change_mode" and a parameter that it accepts and the method in the controller for it would just set the value in the hash and link back to the previous page, but that feels like a hack...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is it a hack? That's how you get information from the browser to the server, through a request.

Comment: @mikhailvs Not sure how else you'd do it :)